# Criar estilo e não estilizar xhtml css

Tags: xhtml

Viva,

Estou a tentar criar um titulo desde tipo: Compras .com

Pretendo que o ".com" esteja a negrito mas não quero usar o "em" porque não é um paragrafo.

Sabem como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS:

### Style sheet:

```
.destaque {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

### HTML:

```
Compras<span class="destaque"> .com</span>
```

Veja também que o html possuí tags de títulos `<h1>` `<h2>`, etc, e que essas tags, por padrão, já usam negrito.